# How to display inlay type hints in Pylance that use (python) aliases?

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I'm using pylance/pyright in VSCode and have activated the following option:

```
"python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true
```

This cause the IDE to suggest type hints in the code. However, the suggested hints do not take in account that I have imported libraries with aliases. For example:

[image]

In the end, if I "double click to insert" the type hint, it's not defined:

[image]

I would expect pylance to insert `pd.DataFrame` instead of just `DataFrame`.

How to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.maybe this can resolve your problem.[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dePaF.png)

Comment: please use your words in addition to the image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541